# Problem with SimpleXML Converter - PersistenceException

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, simple-xml-converter

I try to parse the xml I got from there https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml with XML SimpleXML Converter and I get an exception

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class com.example.nbrbcurrency.retrofit.models.Food

my POJO's

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root

@Root(strict = false, name = "breakfast_menu")
data class BreakFastMenu @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:ElementList(inline = true)
    var foodList : List<Food>
)
```

and

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root

@Root(name = "food")
data class Food @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:Element(name = "name")
    var name: String,

    @field:Element(name = "price")
    var price: String,

    @field:Element(name = "description")
    var description: String,

    @field:Element(name = "calories")
    var calories: String)
```

xml

```
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$7.95</price>
<description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$8.95</price>
<description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>French Toast</name>
<price>$4.50</price>
<description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
<calories>600</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
<price>$6.95</price>
<description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
<calories>950</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. I just predefined properties.

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root

@Root(strict = false, name = "DailyExRates")
data class CurrencyDataList constructor(
    @field:Attribute(name = "Date")
    var date: String = "",
    @field:ElementList(inline = true)
    var currencies: List<CurrencyData> = ArrayList()
)
```